# How to show alert with sound on Website by sending some data/flag from Android app

Tags: javascript, php, android, audio, alert

I am working on app in which I am having one button named as Help, on click of this button I would like to send some notification to the website page, where user will get alert with sound. I am android developer and having very basic knowledge in PHP so I would like to get guidance from PHP experts.

What I think for achieving this feature is :-

1) Creating 1 web service and passing some data/flag from app to this web service.

2) This web service will send some data to page somehow and using that data we can show alert with sound.

Question :-

I know how to pass data using web service from app to web service. But I don;t know how can I show alert from web service on website where user can see it and also playing sound. And I would like to play it constantly until user click on OK or some other button provided on the site.

Please forgive me If my question looks very poor as I am not good in writing. But I am clear what I would like to achieve but don't have the knowledge of how to do that using PHP, so it will be really great if someone can guide me for this and help me a little bit so that I can at least proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need that resource downloaded on your device. I don't think you can stream it. It's not recomanded anyway.
In php just send a json key "play_file": 1 or "play_file": "sound.mp3"

Use the Android documentation for further info.

Comment: you are not getting my question. I want to play sound on my website not on my device. I want to send some flag from my device and would like to show alert on my website not on device.

Comment: So this is a website, not an android application? These two terms are different. On a website you can use HTML5 or a FLASH library to play sounds. If you are building your own application, php does not PLAY media files. You need to send parameters to your application, and your application will play it on the device using the internal software

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a button  with a event to check the flag status and start the sound method.
obs: You can use Javascript for this action.

example: Start a method from clickEvent with a sound loop

```
Method code
 while(flag){
        playSound('UrlToSoundFile');
 }
```

Comment: Souto, you are not getting my question. I want to play sound on my website not on my device. I want to send some flag from my device and would like to show alert on my website not on device.

Comment: Sry, i will change my answer.